Spring MongoDB swallowed exception still causes transaction to roll back
I tried to use MongoTemplate to insert the same user object twice with userId being the _id, the second insert fails due to DuplicateKeyException which is expected, and then the DuplicateKeyException get caught and swallowed.
    @Transactional
    public String createUser(String name) {
        String userId = "12345";
        User user = new User(userId, name);
        mongoTemplate.insert(user);
        try {
            mongoTemplate.insert(user);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException t) {
            log.error("Swallow the exception.");
        }
        return userId;
    }

I am expecting the the transaction to commit successfully because the DuplicateKeyException has been swallowed, but the it fails with the following exception(MongoCommandException:NoSuchTransaction) stack trace:
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction): 'Transaction with { txnNumber: 1 } has been aborted.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"], "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Transaction with { txnNumber: 1 } has been aborted.", "code": 251, "codeName": "NoSuchTransaction", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1730531579, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1730531579, "i": 1}}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:431) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:354) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:743) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:209) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:74) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$OperationCountTrackingConnection.command(DefaultServer.java:299) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableWrite$9(SyncOperationHelper.java:240) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$0(SyncOperationHelper.java:124) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(SyncOperationHelper.java:149) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$1(SyncOperationHelper.java:123) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(SyncOperationHelper.java:149) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(SyncOperationHelper.java:122) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableWrite$10(SyncOperationHelper.java:226) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$decorateWriteWithRetries$11(SyncOperationHelper.java:280) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.executeRetryableWrite(SyncOperationHelper.java:252) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.TransactionOperation.execute(TransactionOperation.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommitTransactionOperation.execute(CommitTransactionOperation.java:94) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommitTransactionOperation.execute(CommitTransactionOperation.java:52) ~[mongodb-driver-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionImpl.commitTransaction(ClientSessionImpl.java:148) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager$MongoTransactionObject.commitTransaction(MongoTransactionManager.java:443) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager.doCommit(MongoTransactionManager.java:230) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager.doCommit(MongoTransactionManager.java:194) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:795) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:758) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:663) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:413) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at davenkin.springboot.web.user.command.UserCommandService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]

